# Can I set a gnome keyboard shortcut to be a prefix key, like in emacs, tmux or screen?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, unity, stumpwm

I would like to setup some Gnome keyboard shortcuts to be a prefix-key, so that I can add several shortcuts with the same prefix.  Eg. I'd like to be able to have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> be a prefix key, with the next letter determining the application to launch:

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> starts firefox
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> starts emacs
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> starts gnome-terminal

Etc.

Also, something like k as a prefix to workspace manipulation commands:

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> workspace left
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> go to workspace 4

and so on.

This is a natural analog to what `emacs`, `tmux` and other applications do with configurable shortcuts, and I can do this with the [stumpwm](https://stumpwm.github.io/) window manager as well, but I wanted to try Unity on my new laptop and was trying to get the same efficient setup I had with `stumpwm`.

Is this provided for in Gnome? Do I have to do some trickery to do this? It would be best if I could find a way to do this in gnome's keyboard shortcut editor.

Comment: I would be particularly interested in seeing this kind of function available for Gnome3 / Gnome-Shell. The lack of keybinding customizability was shocking to me in something that has obviously been thought about quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The program [xchainkeys](https://code.google.com/p/xchainkeys/) does what you need, plus some useful variants of it.
It is independent of the desktop environment.

A possible configuration is to have something like a mode, where you do not need to repeat the prefix key for a series of hotkeys;

With this, instead of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>

typing  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. However, you could workaround that by writing your own program. You would map `Super` + `x` to launch your program, then the program grabs keyboard input and listens to whatever you type next, and launches the desired action.